# running javascript function each MenuItem from Asp:Menu

Tags: javascript, asp.net, menuitem

I want to run an simple javascript function on each MenuItem from an asp:menu.

```
<asp:Menu ID="_mainMenu" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EnableTheming="False"
StaticBottomSeparatorImageUrl="~/Images/menuSeparator.gif" Orientation="Horizontal"
RenderingMode="Table" OnMenuItemClick="_menu_MenuItemClick" SkipLinkText="">
</asp:Menu>
```

If I add the attribute on Page_Init `_mainMenu.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:jsFunction();")` I get onclick event only on a table that describes the menu not on each MenuItem that are links to other pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add css class to the menu:

```
<asp:Menu ID="_mainMenu" runat="server" CssClass="MyMenu" ...
```

Then you can use this jQuery code to handle the click event of all links inside:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".MyMenu a").each(function(index) {
        $(this).click(function() {
            alert($(this).attr("href"));
            return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

The above example will show alert with the link href when it's clicked, you can do whatever you want instead. It will also cancel the link, just remove the "return false;" line to have the link redirect as usual.

Comment: +1. It helped me. can you tell how to show alert on clicking sub menu items ?

Comment: Actually it works fine for top level menu. But does not show message when clicking on sub menu.

Comment: @Pankaj what you mean sub menu? What elements? It will catch clicks only on `<a>` tags to catch more, change the selector.

Comment: I used this HTML `<asp:Menu ID="_mainMenu" RenderingMode="Table" runat="server" CssClass="MyMenu" autopostback="true">
            <Items>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="SubMenu1" Value="Home1"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
                <asp:MenuItem Text="Index" Value="Home">
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="SubMenu1" Value="Home111"></asp:MenuItem>
                </asp:MenuItem>
            </Items>
        </asp:Menu>`

Comment: I used the same JQuery as mentioned by you. But not showing alert on clicking "SubMenu1" in the nested menu

Comment: Check the HTML source - what's the tag of that item?